# Setting Android Home path in ionic framework

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to run my ionic project in android device.So I ran following commands

1. Ionic add ionic-platform-web-client
2. ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin push
3. ionic io init
4. ionic platform add android

All the above commands were successfully executed.When I tried to run following command:

```
 ionic run android
```

It gives me error:

```
'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable is set to non-existent path.
Try update it manually to point to valid SDK directory.
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project.
```

How do i fix it now?

Comment: echo $ANDROID_HOME or echo $PATH , what does this output ? Provided its a linux/macosx machine

Comment: Im using windows.when is run that command it shows me the path of my sdk.I works fine using bash command

Comment: Check the environment variables from the menu then or by typing SET.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ionic build android` before `android run android`

Answer (score 0):

Just set you windows environment for the correct android home path