# cordova build android not working and displaying android studio project detected

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, build

I have an ionic1 project and i am trying to build it.Giving **cordova build android** showing **Android studio project detected** and nothing is getting build .Cordova version is 8.0.0

ionic cordova build android
[WARN] Not performing Ionic build for project type: ionic1.

> cordova build android
>   Android Studio project detected

Running command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" E:\puz\Desalite_Connec
t5\Desalite_Connect\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js E:\puz\Desalit
e_Connect

Can anybody please help me

ionic info

cli packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
Cordova Platforms : android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.1
```

System:

```
Node : v6.4.0
npm  : 3.10.3
OS   : Windows 8.1
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Comment: Does  the console show anything else?

Comment: nothing i am running ionic cordova build android --verbose in cmd and its showin  [DEBUG]: Reason for not using local cli : LOCAL_CLI_NOT_FOUND [DEBUG]:CLI flags: {interactive:true , confirm:false}

Comment: seems like u havent installed the cli. try to run: ionic info and post the output .

Comment: you havent set ANDROID_HOME environment variable...

Comment: I have one ionic-angular 3 project and it's building succesfully

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35715706/setting-android-home-path-in-ionic-framework